# what does "arc" in arcsin, arccos, arctan stands for

Tags: trigonometry

I was just wondering, what does the "arc" in arcsin, arccos, arctan stands for? Is there any particular reason why it is named the way it is?

Comment: [Here](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/54185.html) answers your Q.

Comment: From Latin [*arcus*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/arcus#Etymology_2) : [arc](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/arc#Etymology).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Each of the "original" functions you're inverting takes an angle, so the inverse returns an angle. But thanks to the arc length formula $s=r\theta$, that's equivalent to specifying an arc length.

Answer (score 1):

These functions are the inverse of their respective trigonometric functions. As such they are multiple valued. Taking the *principal value* gives the length of the *arc* on a unit circle subtending an angle that the respective trig function takes as argument.

E.g.
$\arccos(0) = \pi/2 +2k\pi$, $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. The principal value is given by taking $k=0$, and we find the arc length of $\pi/2$ on the unit circle subtends the angle of $\pi/2$ having $\cos(\pi/2)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's work with unit circles because they make everything nice.

As we increase $\theta$ starting from $(0,1)$, you increase $y$. We are used to thinking and calculating $\sin \theta = \frac{y}{r}$.

That is, given a particular $\theta$, we have a $y$-coordinate value.  Since $r = 1$,  $\sin \theta = \frac{y}{r} = y$.  Therefore, $\sin \theta$ is the $y$-coordinate of the point on the unit circle after you have traveled an angular distance of $\theta$.

In addition, the arc length you have travelled is given by $s = r \theta = \theta$.  We may simply recast our previous statement as: $\sin \theta$ is the $y$-coordinate of the point on the unit circle after you have traveled an arc length of $\theta$.

With this setup, we may ask the inverse question: "given a specific $y$ coordinate, what arc length was needed in order to arrive there?".  That arc length, as we discussed above for a unit circle, is the same as the angle. Essentially, this is the ``arc" in the inverse trigonometric functions comes from.

We can read $\theta = \arcsin(y)$ as: "what is the arclength I have travelled along the unit circle to get to $y$?".  Once you know the arc length, you also know the angle since they are the same value.